# Writing in two different places unformatted files in Fortran

Tags: file, fortran, format

I am trying to write in two different places (the main program and a subroutine) unformatted files in my Fortran code. The problem is that when I do it, the results change and I suspect that it is because the memory assignment is overwriting the data that I am using to make the simulation in my CFD code. I ask: Is it possible that one can just use the unformatted file (to write) once in the code? I mean, I have to use the same file to save all my data and not with different files.

I copy and past the two parts of the code to show what I am want to describe:

In the main program, the loop is:

```
         call numcar (isave,suffix)
         longueur=index(nchamp,' ')-1
         nfichier=nchamp(1:longueur)//suffix
         longueur=index(nfichier,' ')-1
         open(10,file=nfichier(1:longueur),form='unformatted')
         write(10) real(uxn,4),real(uyn,4),real(wzn,4),real(ppo,4)
         close(10)
!        *****************************************     
         isave=isave+1
```

and in the subroutine, the loop is:

```
         call numcar (isavediv,suffix1)
         longueur1=index(ndiv,' ')-1
         nfichier1=ndiv(1:longueur1)//suffix1
         longueur1=index(nfichier1,' ')-1
         open(20,file=nfichier1(1:longueur1),form='unformatted')
         write(20) real(ppm,4)
         close(20)
!        *****************************************     
         isavediv=isavediv+1
```

All the variables all declared as `IMPLICIT NONE` in both main program and subroutine.

Comment: First: what results change? The values in the file, the values of your variables during run-time? Second: the variables appear to be different at the two different calls, so if you eliminate one call you need to add the variables from that to the other.

Comment: First: The values of my variables during the run-time change. Second: The variables are different. As you said, I could add the variables from that to the other, but i would like to make the calls in each subroutine. The fact is that: When i do not use the second call, the results of my simulation work good, but when i want to save data with the unformatted statement in the second call, the results of my simulation change. My simulation becomes unstable and i don't understand why are they changing (the run-time data of the simulation) if i am just saving data in files.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.
The problem was that I was using the channel number 20 and a colleague of mine told me that this channel is used by the computer or some devices to process data.
I changed it for channel number 10 and it worked good again.
Thank you for your comments.
Now it looks so:

```
     open(10,file=nfichier1(1:longueur1),form='unformatted')
     write(10) real(ppm,4)
     close(10)
```